# Cannot read from InputStream

Tags: java, jsp

My current code is this:

```
try {
    inputStream is = (new URL(urlpath).openStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int len; (len = is.read(data)) != -1;) {
            os.write(data, 0, len);
        }
        os.flush();
        data = os.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But `is.read(data)` always returns `-1`. I do not understand why it is not working. I used same code at other places, it is working, but in this application, this code is not working. What should be problem with the url path?

Comment: What is the value of urlpath? Also, please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: You don't have `data` defined anywhere or `urlpath`.  Please provide those values so that we can better assist you.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/School/abc.jsp?selectedLetter=d~2015012200001~NOTICE~''.

Comment: Also if you say this exact code works in another place/app then makes sure your app has the appropriate permissions to be making external requests.

Comment: @user1150209 We can't look at he application running on *your* computer!

Comment: Same code is working fine in local environment but it is not working on the server....

Comment: Are actually trying to use the local file system in JSP code? That won't work!

Comment: But some days before it was working too on server.. now it is not working. i did not find out any solution

Comment: It probably means that on the server, nothing is returned from the URL. what happens when you use curl, or open a browser, to contact this address on the server?

Comment: No it is not local file. i use url path and stream the requested url jsp page.

Comment: but when we directly use same link on the url then i can access the page. so i it means the url is correct. but problem the the URL class.

Comment: I already do this but nothing happen.

Comment: You're using localhost. localhost means "the current machine". So, on every machine, it refers to a different machine and server.

Comment: Yes, I changed the host and port for other machine and server. Directly i can access the page but when use the above code it returns nothing. It fails to make connection with the url.

Answer (score 1):

You said this code is meant to run on a server but it works in your local environment.  The reason it's not working is because the server is also being provided with a `localhost` address and that resource is only on your local environment.  Change `localhost` to the IP address of the host that the resource is on and your code will work.

`http://localhost...` <-- will tell the code to look on the same computer that the code is running on which is why the server can't find it.

Change `localhost` to the IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) of the resource your web application is running on.

So if the web application is hosted on `192.168.0.100` then you would do the following:

```
http://192.168.0.100:8080/School/abc.jsp?selectedLetter=d~2015012200001~NOTICE~%27%27
```

Note that since the server needs to reach an external resource to talk to the web application firewall rules will also come into play (you will need to make sure that any firewall is not blocking port 8080 on the host the web application is running on).

Comment: Please tell me what i should check because same code was running some days before

Comment: IP addresses change frequently so double check that your code has the correct IP address for the web application.  Also you should double check that port 8080 is open *on the IP address that the server will connect from* `192.168.0.100:8080` and that it's not just listening on `localhost:8080`

Comment: Have you verified that you can reach the resource from a normal web browser from the network that your client machine is running from?  If you changed data centers then it's possible IP addresses and/or port number and/or firewall rules have changed so it's unlikely that it's your code that is the problem.

Comment: I have checked firewall is off. As i have said that if i directly put url in the address bar and press enter i get the all the data.

Comment: And you directly put the url in the address bar in a web browser that is on the web server that this java code runs from?  Or you checked the url from a web browser on a different machine?  Also have you verified that your app has the appropriate permissions to run?

Comment: Also - does the network the java code run on require a proxy in order to leave or access the network?  You can check the settings of a web browser that can access the intended resource (from inside the same network, of course) to see if it pipes all communications through a proxy.

Comment: One more question - is this a Java applet or a standalone Java application?

Comment: Thanks Max. Now solve this issue. your suggestions help me to solve this. and it was a firewall problem of report server url.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad I could help!  Since my firewall advice helped you solve your issue please accept my answer by checking on the green arrow next to my answer.  Thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

InputStream will return -1 if there is no more data to be read.

See 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[]) for further details.

1. Did you check the content of your request by opening it in a browser?
2. Did you try opening the ports on your server machines firewall?
3. Are you sure you are doing the request correctly with the framework you are using?

Try this

```
InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is )  );

String line = null;
while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )  {
    System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: No it is same as previous. I think after changing data center this problem has occur. Please tell me what should i do.

Comment: problem is that the entire context of how you connect to your server etc. is missing :-(. If you expect an answer that suits you be more specific in your question. Post details, code and stacktraces :-)

Comment: The above code is enough because when i debug code then is.read() always return -1 means url.openStream() did not return anything to the InputStream.

Comment: @user1150209 In your code snipplet noone can see which framework you are using.. If you used that code snipplet before then the error will come from a completely different source probably..

Comment: @user1150209 what did u mean by data center?

Comment: No, I am not using any framework. is it possible that url is https connection . but i also created a connection with https but nothing happen.

Comment: As I want to confirm that if I directly put the url i get the all the data but when i use it the URL class it returns nothing.

Comment: @user1150209 if you are using a https connection, then the certificate you want to use is needed in your java runtime. When using http is wont matter.. I had the same problem once, ut there i forgot to add certain header to my HttpRequest.. Sees to me you use a different kind of request so that wont work either.

Comment: But if it was an certificate error then it must be throw an exception. But it is not throwing any exception.

Comment: I think URL class fail to make connection with the given url. I am not finding out why it fails because same it was working some days before. We just move server to other place and every thing is save here. what should i check?

Comment: server on windows or linux?
Maybe the ip of your local network is wrong check `ipconfig`or `ifconfig`

Comment: It is on windows. It is problem on QA server. In my local system it is working fine and also some days before it was working fine there too.

Comment: is the pc in the same network as the server? Else you would need to adress it via its public ipv4 adress.. (or ipv6 for that matter)